# AngularJS1 Controller not being hit

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a new page in one of our legacy app that uses AngularJS1. As I am not an Angular developer so my knowledge in this technology is almost non-existent. I am actually trying to get my hands dirty in this app as we need to maintain it in future. Here is the HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="text-left">
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Client Admin</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Bob Jones</td>
            <td>BobJones@gmail.com</td>
            <td>Tractor-Tract</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Greenview_Hc</td>
            <td>Hoffmale</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Electronic[Parts]</td>
            <td>Pap</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
Console.log('Hello');
app.controller('testController', ['$http', 'APIService', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$rootScope', 'StatsService', '$state', '$sce', '$translate',
    function ($http, APIService, $scope, $sessionStorage, $rootScope, StatsService, $state, $sce, $translate) {
        var myCtrl = this;
        myCtrl.title = "Hello World";
        debugger;        
}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('testingApp', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            initialData: '=info',
        },
        templateUrl: 'test/test.html',
        controller: 'testController',
        controllerAs: 'tc'
    };
});
```

The issue is I can not get the controller to get hit. Even the console is not showing anything. What is wrong with this code? This is my very first try at Angular and I am using existing code to create my testing page.

---

### EDIT:

I went through the app and tried to understand its architecture. Here is what I found:

All the controllers are defined in `app-controller.js` with code. Yes, this file has complete controller code and there are individual controllers as well with the same code. For example if there is a controller "MyController.js" it has its own code and the same code is written in `app-controller.js` as well

All the directives are defined in `app-directives.js`

There is a config file with code like:

```
$stateProvider.state('index.testing', {
  url: "/testing",
  templateUrl: "testing/testing.html",
  controller: "testingController",
  controllerAs: "testing",
  data: {
    requireLogin: true,
    accessPage: 'Test.aspx',
    pageTitle: "Testing View"
  }
```

`index.html` includes only `config.js`

Comment: your controller is executed in a directive. You would need to have your directive in HTML first (as `testing-app`)

Comment: For creating pages, use components and not directives. Also, please do check if you have not missed to include the new controller file in your index.html.

Comment: As @AlekseySolovey mentioned, you need to instantiate your directive by adding it in HTML as `<testing-app info="someObjectWithInfo"></testing-app>`. Also your `Console.log('Hello');` should be inside your controller function, not outside

Comment: I would suggest to get your hands dirty with angular basics. https://angularjs.org

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks. I've edited my question. I can't understand the architecture. Maybe I need to follow the existing way. Please look at the edit again.

Answer (score 1):

For the "controller to be hit", the directive needs to be included in the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <testing-app info="'world'">
    </testing-app>
</body>
```

### The DEMO

```js
app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.directive('testingApp', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            initialData: '<info',
        },
        template: `<fieldset>
                      title={{tc.title}}
                   </fieldset>`,
        controller: 'testController',
        controllerAs: 'tc',
        bindToController: true
    };
});
app.controller('testController',
    function () {
        var myCtrl = this;
        myCtrl.$onInit = function() {
            myCtrl.title = "Hello "+myCtrl.initialData;
            console.log("Hello", myCtrl.title);
           debugger; 
       };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Testing App</h1>
    <testing-app info="'world'">
    </testing-app>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question. I can't understand the architecture. Maybe I need to follow the existing way. Please look at the edit again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't call AngularJS legacy. AngularJS is still widely used and supported, and a majority in the so called angular world. Have a look at this [Google trends comparison](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=AngularJS,Angular2,Angular4).

Secondly, to now actually address your question hehe.

I assume that the first HTML snippet is the `test.html` file contents.
I would recommend re-writing that in the more angular way, using ng-repeat for the `<tr>`s

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="text-left">
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Client Admin</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="dataEntry in testController.initialData">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="dataEntry.select"/></td>
            <td>{{dataEntry.clientAdmin}}</td>
            <td>{{dataEntry.email}}</td>
            <td>{{dataEntry.company}}</td>
            <td>{{dataEntry.location}}</td>
            <td>{{dataEntry.users}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In order for your `<table>` HTML code to render somewhere, you need to instantiate your directive there, as such:

```
<!-- Page HTML -->
<!-- someObjectWithInfo would come the controller of this page -->
<testing-app info="someObjectWithInfo"></testing-app>
<!-- Page HTML -->
```

P.S. Your Console.log('Hello'); should be inside your controller function, not outside, as such:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$http', 'APIService', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$rootScope', 'StatsService', '$state', '$sce', '$translate',
    function ($http, APIService, $scope, $sessionStorage, $rootScope, StatsService, $state, $sce, $translate) {
        var myCtrl = this;
        myCtrl.title = "Hello World";
        console.log("Hello", myCtrl.title);
        debugger;        
}]);
```

Hope this helps :)